# Opting out of PageRank

Tags: web-apps, search-engine

Every search engine I have seen is based of some form of PageRank. PageRank is a popularity contest: websites that have links to them get more popular, more so if the websites linking to them are popular.

In my experience PageRank is as much hindrance as help:
since most websites connect to similar websites bigger networks [drown out smaller networks](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-022-05434-1). The rich get richer.

I am looking for a search engine that allows disabling PageRank. Ideally I would be able to tune the "weight" of PageRank (in comparison to how well the queries match). Also, I would like to see negation, exact match, and other standard search engine features.